# How to use a second router-outlet in angular2 app?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular2 app in which I would like to have 2 router-outlets. I have been trying to get this to work after looking at many blogs, and google searches. But it is not working. Any suggestions as to why it is not working, and how I can get it to work would be greatly appreciated.

The relevant part of the routing module looks like this

```
  {
    path:"booking",
    component:Booking_com,
    outlet:"bookingRouter"
  },
```

I have some html in a template home.html

```
<div id="footer">
    <!--<p>Routeroutlet content goes below</p>-->
    <router-outlet name="bookingRouter"></router-outlet>
    <button class="bookingButton" md-fab id="fab"(click)="openBookings()"><img src="../../assets/icons/suitcase.png" id="bookingImage" class="icon"></button>
</div>
```

the relevant function in home.component.html looks like this

```
  openBookings(){
    this.router.navigate( ["/booking"] );
  }
```

The html for the component Booking_com looks like this

```
<p>hi</p>
```

The actual relevant user interface looks like this 
[image]

When you look at the user interface, I want to click the red button and have the text 'hi' appear below where it says "Routeroutlet content goes below" by routing to the Booking_com component, but this is not working and if anybody has a suggestion for why this is not working and/or how to fix it I would be greatly appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code as text, not as images.

Comment: Ok sorry, hold on.

Comment: Also, explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It says in the end what I want to achieve. I would like the text "hi" to appear in the second router-outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify under which router outlet you want your content to appear. Redirecting from TypeScript should look like:

```
openBookings(){
    this.router.navigate( ["/booking"], { outlets: { bookingRouter: ['booking'] );
}
```

Redirecting using anchor tag:

```
<a [routerOutlet]="[{ outlets: { bookingRouter: ['booking']}}]">To Booking</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but when change the code to this option this.router.navigate( ["/booking"], { outlets: { bookingRouter: ['booking'] );

Comment: I get an error that says  Argument of type '{ outlets: { bookingRouter: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'outlets' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.

Comment: @Dan  have a look at this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html and see Milestone 4 that discusses secondary router outlets.